# Why does MATLAB sprintf('%.15g',-1*0) print '-0'?

Tags: matlab

Why am I getting the following in MATLAB? Tried in 2015b and 2019a and same result.

```
sprintf('%.15g',-1*0)

ans =

    '-0'
```

Comment: What did you expect it to print?

Comment: 0? Since when is 0 signed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`format hex` shows you what's going on - IEEE double precision numbers can have negative zero.

```
>> format hex
>> 0
ans =
   0000000000000000
>> -0
ans =
   8000000000000000
```

Comment: Thank you. As a developer in also C and C#, I don't think I have ever seen this until now.